# how can i perform discrete integration of gyroscope data?

Tags: c++, c, robotics, sensors, tilt-sensor

gyroscopes which measure rate of rotation of angles when integrated produce angles right?
my question is how do i do this? what im doing so far is just adding all the angles ive detected and that seems to be very wrong

```
AngleIntegrated = GyroDegPersec * (1/GyroBandWidth);
```

suggestions are very welcome. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that of course you can't count on having a correct value in the long run (by integration your error window will always increase over time) what I would do is reading the gyroscope, interpolating the current read and previous few ones to get a smooth curve (e.g. a parabola using current read and previous two) and then computing the integral of that parabola from last read time and current time.

Comment: thanks for the reply! is that something like RungeKutta 2nd order sir?

Comment: Runga Kutta uses 4 points, so the current and previous 3. As a result, it does give a good estimate of the value 1.5 periods ago. This delay is the price paid for a better estimator. You can decrease the delay by altering the weights, but this also decreases the quality of the smoothing.

Comment: @MSalters and 6502 Do you have any example of such implementations?

Comment: @sam: It's so trivial I don't bother, just `(1*x[-3]+3*x[-2]+3*x[-1]+x[0])/8`

Answer (score 2):

You need to integrate *with respect to time*. So ideally you should sample the gyroscope at regular (fixed) time intervals, T, and then incorporate that sampling interval, T, into your integral calculation.

Note that T needs to be small enough to satisfy the Nyquist criterion.

Comment: thank you for replying. im sampling my gyroscope as soon as it has new data to offer, going by its bandwidth of 50 hz. im sampling at (1/50) seconds. what should my code be to actually perform this integral calculation?

Comment: @user571099: OK, if `1/GyroBandWidth` is your sample interval (`T` in my answer above) then yes, your calculation is essentially correct. However note that for accurate results you should probably implement a proper integrator, rather than just summing.

Comment: sorry for being noobish, how do i do a proper integrator? im only using c. i cant think of any other way to do integration other than summing

Comment: @user571099: normally digital integrators are designed to have a frequency response which eliminates the problem of accumulating any small constant error in the input signal (a small DC offset will obviously get accumulated into a large error value over time if you just keep summing).

Comment: suppose ,in C code sir, how do i perform a digital integration?

Comment: A frequency response filter only helps to reduce or eliminate error terms ε(t) at frequencies where they dominate the real ω(t). And obviously a constant ε only has frequency 0. So, if your measured data has a DC component, this will inevitably be lost by a filter that eliminates the constant ε (has a pole at f=0)

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate in discrete domain. Suppose the angular rate is da, it's time integral is a.
k is the discrete step number.

```
a(k) = a(k-1) + T*0.5*(da(k) + da(k-1))
```

For example, da(k) is current angular rate reading. da(k-1) is previoud angular rate reading. a(k-1) is the previous step's integration value(rotation angle). T is sampling rate. If the sensor outputs in every 1 millisecond, T becomes 0.001.

You can use this formula when k>0. The initial value, a(0), must be given.